# how to make a cross section of a shape obtained using surfer(D2(:,1),D2(:,2),D2(:,3))

Tags: matlab, matlab-figure, figure

I have a surf game console(D2(:,1),D2(:,2),D2(:,3)). I need to make a cross section of this figure and get a two-dimensional curve. How to do it? I tried using a slice that doesn't work because it has to be a three-dimensional array.[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4Ndwq.png)

I tried to find all variables with the same value, for example, y finds only one point in the array. At the same time, the figure is built.